# Deploy programatically created KIE-Drools-Artifact to Maven repository

Tags: drools, kie

Is there a way to deploy a programatically created Drools 6 artifact to the underlying maven repository? I do NOT want to explicitly somehow call `mvn deploy` but do that from the program itself:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ruleString = "rule \"TestRule\"\nthen\nSystem.out.println(\"This is a testrule.\");\nend";

    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

    KieModuleModel kieModuleModel = kieServices.newKieModuleModel();
    KieBaseModel kieBaseModel = kieModuleModel.newKieBaseModel("testbase1").setDefault(true);
    KieSessionModel kieSessionModel = kieBaseModel.newKieSessionModel("testsession1").setDefault(true).setType(KieSessionModel.KieSessionType.STATELESS);

    KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
    kieFileSystem.generateAndWritePomXML(new ReleaseIdImpl("de.itm.test", "testartifact", "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"));
    kieFileSystem.write("src/main/resources/testbase1/rule1.drl", ruleString);

    KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem).buildAll();

    // how to now deploy the new artifact so it is available on disc, e.g. in ~/.m2/repository/de/itm/test/test/testartifact/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ ?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you can see a unit test that does what you are asking for:

https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/master/kie-ci/src/test/java/org/kie/scanner/KieScannerIncrementalCompilationTest.java#L63

Basically:

```
MavenRepository repository = MavenRepository.getMavenRepository();
repository.deployArtifact(releaseId, kJar1, kPom);
```

Comment: Thank you, I also found the https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-integration/blob/master/kie-remote/kie-services-client/src/main/java/org/kie/services/client/deployment/KieModuleDeploymentHelperImpl.java . I will try to re-implement that part of Guvnor/KIE-WB in my own program, although I am currently struggling with the resourceFilePaths ...

Comment: Does this upload to KIE' maven repo in remote kie repositroy?

Comment: @ArunGeorge it does if you configured the remote repo in the maven settings.xml file.

Comment: @Edson . Can you provide an example.I have seen the kie-ci testcases and did not find anything which does this.

Comment: The test I linked on my answer above uses a custom settings.xml file here: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/kie-ci/src/test/filtered-resources/kie-ci-tests-custom-settings.xml