# How to add a few non open source jars to Artifactory so that they can be pulled by another Gradle/Maven project

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jar, artifactory

In my Gradle/Maven build script there are a few jars that are not available for download from maven repository because they are not open source. (These jars were developed by some projects in my organization anymore that are not being worked on anymore).

My requirement is to add these jars to an Artifactory with group id, artifact id and version number. In this way when I point my repository to Artifactory in my build script, these jars can be pulled out.

I am looking for mvn-install kind of command for Artifactory.

I also found below question while researching :
[Deploying project JAR to artifactory programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517243/deploying-project-jar-to-artifactory-programmatically) but this does not specify group id, artifact id and version number that I need so that another project's Maven/Gradle build script can pull that jar from Artifactory.

The Artifactory is locally deployed in my system at the moment (later on it will be moved to a server).

Comment: Just manually upload those jars once and afterwars you can use them as usual dependencies in both Maven and Gradle.

Comment: i can manually add it yes, but how do i give it group id, artifact id and version number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy those JAR's via Artifactory WebUI and when doing the deploy use the "Deploy as Maven Artifact" That will deploy those artifacts with the correct group id, artifact id and version number.
See [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Deploying+Artifacts#DeployingArtifacts-DeployingMavenArtifacts)

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out a few hours after posting this question. This is the correct answer though.